# How to read CSV file with of data frame with row names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file  (`tmp.csv`) that looks like this:

```
        x       y       z
bar     0.55    0.55    0.0
foo     0.3     0.4     0.1
qux     0.0     0.3     5.55
```

It was created with Pandas this way:

```
    In [103]: df_dummy 
    Out[103]: 
          x     y     z
    bar  0.55  0.55  0.00
    foo  0.30  0.40  0.10
    qux  0.00  0.30  5.55

   In [104]: df_dummy.to_csv("tmp.csv",sep="\t")
```

What I want to do is to read that CSV into the same dataframe representation.
I tried this but doesn't give what I want:

```
In [108]: pd.io.parsers.read_csv("tmp.csv",sep="\t")
Out[108]: 
  Unnamed: 0     x     y     z
0        bar  0.55  0.55  0.00
1        foo  0.30  0.40  0.10
2        qux  0.00  0.30  5.55
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`index_col`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_table.html) parameter:

```
>>> pd.io.parsers.read_csv("tmp.csv",sep="\t",index_col=0)
        x     y     z
bar  0.55  0.55  0.00
foo  0.30  0.40  0.10
qux  0.00  0.30  5.55
```